# ¿Como restringir aplicación java según país?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

habrá alguna forma de restringir una aplicación según el país en el que se encuentra el dispositivo?.

Por ejemplo, quiero impedir que usuarios de USA tengan acceso a la aplicación, enviándolos desde el Splash a un Activity en el cual muestro un mensaje en su idioma, aclarando que la app no esta en su región.

Este es un ejemplo de lo anterior:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Restrict_region">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:background="@color/columncolor">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="361dp"
            android:layout_height="671dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="137dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                        android:text="@string/region_no_disponible"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#E7E1E1"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

creo que con 
`getNetworkCountryIso()` y `getSimCountryIso()` se puede, pero no se como hacerlo.. alguien tiene idea de como integrarlo?

Comment: Hola puedes restringir tu aplicación en play console de google, hay una opción Presencia en Google Play store luego precio y distribucion y gestionar paises , ahí puedes modificar los paises en donde quieres que se instale tu aplicación

Comment: si lose, pero si la publico en otro lado tambien o usan VPN no quiero que la usen

Comment: Entonces utiliza los métodos que mencionas, `getNetworkCountryIso()` y `getSimCountryIso()` en tu splash y según el resultado redirige a donde quieras. Mira esto https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde la [**consola Google Play**](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) se puede restringir el uso de tu aplicación.

Desde el menú derecho ve a `Store presence` (`Presencia en Google Play store`) > `Pricing & Distribution` (`Precio y Distribución`), ve a la sección "Countries" (Países) y ahí puedes administrar en que países podrá estar disponible tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> pero si la publico en otro lado también o usan VPN

Una forma de realizar esto puede ser mediante el método:

> **[getNetworkCountryIso()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso())**  Devuelve el código de país ISO
>   equivalente al MCC (código de país móvil) del operador registrado
>   actual o la celda cercana, si está disponible.

Pero es muy importante saber que obtener el MCC (Mobile Country Code) funciona en todos los dispositivos GSM, pero no es confiable en redes CDMA.

Para usar el método **[TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso())** es importante definir el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

y además realizar la petición manual de este permiso, para eso agrega los métodos en tu `Activity`:

```
   //Requiere el permiso.
    public  boolean isPermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v("Permission","Permission is granted");
                    return true;
                } else {

                    Log.v("Permission","Permission is revoked");
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 2);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
                Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            }
        }


       //Determina si el permiso fue aceptado por el usuario.
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 2: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //do your specific task after read phone state granted
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return;
                }
                // other 'case' lines to check for other
                // permissions this app might request
            }
        }
```

y agrega también el método para determinar el código del país de 2 dígitos (ISO 3166-1) en el cual se encuentra tu dispositivo,  por ejemplo Argentina sería "ar", México, "mx", Romania, "ro", etc.:

```
  public static String getCountryCode(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
    }
```

aquí puedes ver una lista de los códigos:
https://datahub.io/core/country-list/r/0.html

Este sería un  ejemplo de como determinar si el código del país esta permitido para usar tu aplicación, de otra forma cierra la `Activity` principal y por lo tanto la aplicación:

```
    List<String> countryCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Crea lista de paises permitidos
        countryCodes.add("ar");
        countryCodes.add("mx");
        countryCodes.add("ro");
        countryCodes.add("cu");
        countryCodes.add("do");
        countryCodes.add("pa");
        countryCodes.add("es");

        if(isPermissionGranted()){
            Log.i(TAG, getPhoneStatus(getApplicationContext()));
            if(!countryCodes.contains(getCountryCode(getApplicationContext()))){
                //No permitida en este pais.
                finish();
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Neyunse un placer ayudarte, saludos.